# How to connect postgresql in datatables?

Tags: php, postgresql, datatable

i had created and connected datatables to postgresql.

this is my connection code. may i have two connection called pg_query, and how i can make a right code? i try for 2 days and still stuck

```
<?php
$conn = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=password";
$connection = pg_connect($conn);
if (!$connection) {
print("failed");
exit;
}
else print("Connection Success");
?>
```

this is my datatables code

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");

$params = $columns = $totalRecords = $data = array();

$params = $_REQUEST;

$columns = array( 
    0 =>'id',
    1 =>'employee_name', 
    2 => 'employee_salary',
    3 => 'employee_age'
);

$where = $sqlTot = $sqlRec = "";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY employee_name";
$sqlTot .= $sql;
$sqlRec .= $sql;


$sqlRec .=  "ORDER BY employee_name";

$queryTot = pg_query($conn, $sqlTot)or die("database error:");

$totalRecords = pg_num_rows($queryTot);

$queryRecords = pg_query($conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

while( $row = pg_fetch_row($queryRecords) ) { 
    $data[] = $row;
}   

$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => 1,   
    "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),  
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
    "data"            => $data  
);

echo json_encode($json_data);  

print_r ($json_data);
?>
```

But, i'm getting error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter to `pg_query` should be connection you get from `pg_connect`.
What you actually pass is variable `$conn` where you have string with connection specification (username etc).

To fix your problem, instead of `$conn` use variable `$connection` where you store actual connection returned by `pg_connect` on line:

```
$connection = pg_connect($conn);
```

So for example instead of:

```
$queryTot = pg_query($conn, $sqlTot)or die("database error:");
```

there should be:

```
$queryTot = pg_query($connection, $sqlTot)or die("database error:");
```